# Cannot run react-native app directly on iPhone (deployment target errors)

Tags: ios, react-native

**The problem**

When I run react-native in Simulator it works fine. I am now trying to run it on my iPhone directly connected to my MacBook but issues are coming up. There are several warnings that say the `Deployment Target is set to 7.0`.

Where exactly is this being set? IS it being set in the libraries that I am using? How do I get around this?

Similar information I have found that do not seem to be duplicates of this issue include:

- People having issues with the simulator (the simulator is working fine for me)
- Suggestions for people to use the Legacy Build system in XCode (which others are saying is not a good idea).

So, what exactly is causing this issue and what do I do to fix it so that I can run the app on my physical iPhone device?

**The error messages:**

```
ThePrompt$ react-native run-ios --device "Fred’s iPhone"

warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-zip-archive: https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide. 
info Found Xcode workspace "TestAppApp07.xcworkspace" 
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace TestAppApp07.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme TestAppApp07 -destination id=1e8ce3b4030eadba1161bda6bc1109b1e215f1ca -derivedDataPath build/TestAppApp07") 
....................... 
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening TestAppApp07.xcworkspace. Run CLI with 
--verbose flag for more details. 
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /opt/TestAppApp07/ios/build/TestAppApp07

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build 
note: Constructing build description 
Build system information 
error: Signing for "TestAppApp07Tests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'TestAppApp07Tests')

Build system information 
error: Signing for "TestAppApp07" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'TestAppApp07')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNFS')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNGestureHandler')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNScreens')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNSound')


2019-08-15 00:01:44.888 xcodebuild[36925:1330679]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 1e8ce3b4030eadba1161bda8ac1109b1e215f1us was NULL
2019-08-15 00:01:44.927 xcodebuild[36925:1330675]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 1e8ce3b4030eadba1161bda8ac1109b1e215f1us was NULL
** BUILD FAILED **
```

**The issue?**

It seems that React Native is only supporting a deployment target of 7.0. However, the newer version of XCode no longer has 7.0 as a target option. The lowest target in new versions of XCode is 8.0.

**Legacy Build?**

Some of the issues I see say I can use Legacy Build instead. However, I am wondering if this is will cause any other issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is the development team:

> Build system information 
>   error: Signing for "TestAppApp07Tests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'TestAppApp07Tests')
>
> Build system information  error: Signing for "TestAppApp07" requires a
>   development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in
>   target 'TestAppApp07')

Just set a valid development team. If you don't have one, create it. After setting a correct development team it should work.

Make sure you set the team for both targets: `TestAppApp07` and `TestAppApp07Tests`

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/how-to-test-your-ios-application-on-a-real-device.html

https://developer.apple.com/support/teams/

About the deployment target:

[image]

If the problem related to deployment target is related to some old dependencies I think you can use the Legacy build system.

From what I know Xcode 8 or newer has no support for deployment target iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix will you need to set the deployment target of device version you are using.

If project deployment target has been set to 8 then you can not run it on iOS 7 or below it. Make sure you should have set the minimum deployment target which you want to support.
That is can be set in below window.
[image]

Comment: The problem is that the target has 8.0 as the lowest possible target.

Comment: Try: Adding a new simulator with iOS 7 version if works then fine otherwise you have to use a lower version of XCode

Comment: @kojow7: are you able to run other app in device? as per error message it's related to setup signing identity issue to run the app in device. So can you please check development , provisioning is right or not?

Comment: @Shubham I think the problem is that React Native is set for a target of 7.0 but xCode's lowest target is 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> appc run -p ios -T device

If the issue persist then try with the following steps

1. Delete certificate from the login keychain and try with the newly created certificate and provisioning profile.
2. Reconnect the device

Answer (score 0):

```
Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNFS')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNGestureHandler')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNScreens')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to
7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.4.99. (in target 'RNSound')
```

It is clearly saying that your deployment target is set to 7.0, but Xcode support starts from 8.0.
To set the deployment target.

1. Open Project settings.
2. Select Target ***Your project name***
3. Choose ***General***
4. Go to ***Deployment info -> Deployment Targer***

If you still find errors, then check for your third-party frameworks for compatibility issues.

Try to avoid legacy system build, because it might comes with several other issues in device.

Comment: New versions of xCode are not able to be set to 7.0.

Comment: True, they don't support iOS 7.0. Minimum deployment target is 8.0 If you see practically, there are very rare devices running iOS 7.0. Along with that, all your RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNScreens, RNSound targets have minimum deployment target of 8.0 @kojow7