# React Native 0.66 iOS crashes on AppDelegate RCTRootView init

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to upgrade our RN project to 0.66 (from 0.63). When I build the project in debug mode, the app crashes on startup due to `uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[REAEventDispatcher setBridge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002f51cc0'` when initializing the `RCTRootView` in the `AppDelegate.m` file (entire file at the end).

After some googling, I found the `unrecognized selector` bit is because some function is undefined on an object.  The error is marked in the code, its about halfway through the file.

I need some help finding out why this function isn't available (or what else is wrong). As far as I can see, the files have an implementation of the functions that are called. Am I missing any imports? Not that well versed in Swift, only used it in combination with React Native.

I haven't made a reproducible example, but I hope someone else has come over this already in porting to this version. If you need any more information, please ask. I've also attached the podfile below the relevant file.

`Appdelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import "RNBootSplash.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#import <Firebase.h>


#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper =
      [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc]
                            initWithRootNode:application
                        withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc]
                        initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  if([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil){
    [FIRApp configure];
  }

   [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyC-BV0Dp46BQ1iP1HRws-oP_90FV0Aewfo"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions]
  //This is where the application crashes
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge 
                                                   moduleName:@"Flatz"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
  
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f
                                                      green:1.0f
                                                       blue:1.0f
                                                      alpha:1];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"LaunchScreen" rootView:rootView]; // <- initialization using the storyboard file name

  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  return
      [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"
                                                     fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main"
                                 withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

@end
```

`Podfile`

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Flatz' do

  # No individual tracking of people or their phones
  $RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true

  # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config["reactNativePath"],
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )


  target 'FlatzTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        #1
        deployment_target = config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
          #2
          target_components = deployment_target.split
            #3
            if target_components.length > 0
              #4
              target_initial = target_components[0].to_i
                #5
                if target_initial < 9
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = "9.0"
                end
            end
        end
     end

     installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
     end
  end

   permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
    pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
end
```

Comment: Did you follow the [RN Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.0&to=0.66.0) instructions for a transition from 0.63 to 0.66?

Comment: I did not know that was a thing. I'll check back in after doing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As jnpdx pointed out, I needed to follow the [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.0&to=0.66.0). Turns out there were quite a few steps I had missed doing it without it.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had the iOS Deployment target under build settings on 9, while on the Podfile on 11. Changing to 11 solved the problem, see [how to change iOS Deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997165/13259289). Also, remember to npx [react-native-clean-project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).